# Is there a way to Typecast a query input field from ID to UUID to make the request in Apollo Graphql?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

So i'm facing in issue where server implementation for some reason they have used scalar UUID in the schema on a new graphql api repository when all other repos have consistently used ID everywhere so far. And i'm facing problem extending my nested query with a new request that uses a UUID in the server and my params that's being currently used for other queries are of type ID. Any way to type cast it to make a request? A custom directive? Thanks

```
tStars(tStarsInput: StarsInput!): Stars!

input StarsInput {
  yearId: ID! //in the server this is defined as UUID!
}

query activities(
  $yearId: ID! 
) 
//many existing queries that use yearId which is an ID!
...
...
//now new query that I need to pass yearId as a UUID! instead of ID!
{
  tStars(
    tStarsInput: {
      yearId: $yearId // as UUID! somehow?
    }
  ) {
    id
    desc
  }
}
```